# Backbone View overriding the render function loses childviews

Tags: backbone.js

I'm trying to run some code to resize a div after my header is done rendering. I have looked at answers here and the Backbone documentation. this is what I wrote:

```
Backbone.View.extend({
    template: header_tpl,
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template({});

        setTimeout(function() {
           $(window).on("resize",function(){
               $(".somediv").height($(".someotherdiv").height())
           })
           .resize()
        }, 0);

        return this;
    },
    childViews: {
       // Some childViews in here
    }
});
```

This works, but the childViews in this view won't render. I think it has to do with the empty object being passed on the this.template(). The backbone docs say to pass on this.model.attributes, but this view doesn't have a model. Its a simple header with no data being passed on to it.

Comment: Is this a Backbone.View or some other kid of view? Can you show more of your code for the view please

Comment: Its inside of a Backbone.View.extend()

Comment: @CoryDanielson I added some more code

Comment: You're creating a standard Backbone.View. It does not do anything with childViews. Are you working in a large codebase? Look at another View that does work and see if it also extends from Backbone.View

Comment: @CoryDanielson I'm working in a very large codebase. All the views extend the Backbone.View

Comment: So there must be something custom built into Backbone.View that makes it do things with childViews. Backbone.View will not render them by default. If you look at the source code, there are no references to childViews http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html

Comment: After the template it rendered, you need to manually render the childViews and stick them into this.$el something... if it's not done automatically by some custom code you have there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @CoryDanielson 's comment, Backbone has no default handling of "childViews". If your job is to make a Backbone View render it's child Views, there are lots of reasonably simple ways to do that.

But I think what you are really trying to do is to keep some sort of pre-built `render` functionality that is built into `Backbone.View` somewhere else in your codebase. Since the only extension you seem to need is attaching a `resize` event to `window`, maybe the best option is to not do this in the `render` method, then you can continue to use whatever is pre-built elsewhere in your codebase.

```
Backbone.View.extend({
  template: header_tpl,
  // no override of render
  initialize: function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
       $(window).on("resize",function(){
           $(".somediv").height($(".someotherdiv").height())
       })
       .resize()
    }, 0);
  },
  childViews: {
   // Some childViews in here
  }
});
```

This code should attach the event when the view is instanced, not at each render.

Of course, if your Codebase may also be altering the default `initialize` method, we really can't know. In that case, there might be some options to override the default methods (`initialize`, `render`, ...) just by extending, but still calling the old methods under the hood.

Comment: I see. I'm working on an implementation of Backbone managed by Netsuite for SuiteCommerce Advanced. They must have created this custom childViews. I'm going to try to find it in the source code. SCA is massive and I have only been able to see a portion of it.

Comment: You were 100% right. SCA has a module of backbone extras that was overriding the default Backbone.View.render

Comment: Nice when guesses pan out :) You should check if they also override the `initialize` method - if they do, the above solution may break something else. If the customizations don't leave anywhere nice to fit your resize function in, there are some good ways to override a `render` (or whatever) but still call the default within the override. Let me know if you need any thoughts on that...